# Nuxt.js custom store folder

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I tried to change vuex store path that is used by nuxt.js by default. I want my store path to be 'modules/my-module/store/store.js'. Is there any way I can do this? Or maybe I can somehow add my module store to existing store from nuxt module file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can register a store module dynamically using the `registerModule` function.

Let's say you have your **my-module** module and inside you have your `index.vue` file. Inside that file you can register you module's store like this:

```
import store from './store'; //import your module store
export default {
  name: 'my-module',
  computed: {
    ...
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.registerModule('myModuleStore', store);
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('myModuleStore/someAction'); //example of action for your module's store
  },
};
```

I recommend you this [medium](https://medium.com/3yourmind/large-scale-vuex-application-structures-651e44863e2f) article that suggests some good vue.js application structures, including store modules where it shows how to register a private module